# Windows Security Credentials when Using GPO (Group Policy Editor)

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, active-directory, firewall, group-policy

I've a problem to be clear and short:

I wanted to add some users for a restriction (Deny Log through Network), in Users Rights Assignment in GPO And then, Windows is Asking for my credentials (User + Password) When I want to add these Users.. And the problem when I put my Credentials, it doesn't work.

> From where I can disable this option of credential?

ERROR MESSAGE:

[image]

Comment: One thing that would help is to get the error message in English as well...see here for why: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/non-english-question-policy/

Comment: Check the **domain**. If you are trying to add guest or localuser, change the domain to local computer

Answer (score 1):

If you edit the GPO via an administrator workstation with the RSAT tool kit, be sure the relationship between the domain and the workstation is ok.

If you are editing that directly on the domain controller, please run dcdiag and be sure your domain is healthy, as you got a lookup error in your Active Directory, and it's a bad sign.